# How to fetch matrix block items with the ElementAPI

Tags: assets, elementcriteriamodel, plugin-elementapi

I have a question regarding the ElementAPI:

I am sucessfully using the ElementAPI to fetch assets related to an entry. Now I have a matrix field where a user can add multiple galleries (multiple block of selected assets) and i want to retrieve the images. But I can't figure out how to use it for nested matrix blocks...

This is how I fetch the data with ElementAPI from non-matrix assets fields (`elementapi.php` config)

```
'endpoints' => [
    'api/v1/installation-views/<sourceEntryId:\d+>/<fieldHandle:[A-Za-z]+>' => function($sourceEntryId, $fieldHandle) {
        return [
            'elementType' => 'Asset',
            'criteria' => [
                'relatedTo' => [
                    'sourceElement' => $sourceEntryId,
                    'field' => $fieldHandle
                ],
                'kind' => 'image'
            ],
            'transformer' => function(AssetFileModel $asset) {
                return [
                    'id' => $asset->id,
                    'title' => $asset->title,
                    ...
                ];
            },
        ];
    }
]
```

How would I do that for asset fields nested inside a matrix block? I guess I can't use the nested field handle as handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrix blocks are elements just like entries and assets, so this is just a matter of setting the `elementType` to `'MatrixBlock'`, and adjusting your `criteria` to fetch the block you’re after.

The simplest approach would be to pass the Matrix block ID in the URL, and apply it to the `id` criteria parameter.

```php
'endpoints' => [
    'matrix-blocks/<blockId:\d+>' => function($blockId) {
        return [
            'elementType' => 'MatrixBlock',
            'criteria' => [
                'id' => $blockId
            ],
            'first' => true, // Just return one Matrix block
            'transformer' => function(MatrixBlock $block) {
                $assetsInfo = [];

                foreach ($block->myAssetsfield as $asset) {
                    $assetsInfo[] = [
                        'url' => $asset->url,
                        'title' => $asset->title,
                        // ...
                    ];
                }

                return [
                    'id' => $block->id,
                    'assets' => $AssetsInfo,
                    // ...
                ];
            },
        ];
    }
]
```

You can also use the following criteria parameters to narrow down the search:

- `fieldId` (the Matrix field ID)
- `ownerId` (the owner element ID, e.g. your entry’s ID)
- `ownerLocale` (the locale of the owner element that the block should have been saved to)
- `type` (the block type handle)

Comment: Thank you! Seems easier than I thought. One little question. My matrix block has an assets field. Can I get them directly from $block or would I have to make an additional query?

Comment: @RobertKrieg Just updated my answer with an example of adding assets info to the response.